# How to create a frontpage that lists all the nodes in the site using drupal views

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I want to create a frontpage view that will display all the nodes in my site. What I do now is as simple as this:

1. Navigate to views module.
2. Activate the frontpage view.
3. Select page view.

My doubt is now how and where do I specify that this front page should display me all the modes in the site ?

Thanks, I can be more clear if anybody want's more information..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After enabling the frontpage view, you have to set your frontpage to the path of the frontpage view, which is frontpage out of the box.  To do this, go to Administer > Site Configuration > Site Information and set the Default front page to frontpage.

The frontpage view will show all nodes which have been Promoted to Frontpage (set under Publishing Options on the node form).  You can change this by editing the frontpage view and removing the Node: Promoted to front page filter under Filters.

Hope that helps.

~Matt

Comment: Hi Thanks, 

What I did not know was to set the Publishing options in the node form.